# Hibernate returning null values depending on 'max_fetch_depth' - issue with entity model?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-6.x

We have upgraded to Hibernate 6.2.6 Final, and have an entity model that looks as follows:

```
┌──────────────────┐       ┌───────────┐
│Step Configuration│1─────*│ FormOption│
└──────────────────┘       └───────────┘
                                 1
                                 │
                                 │
                                 1
                           ┌───────────┐       ┌────┐
                           │FormVersion│*─────1│Form│
                           └───────────┘       └────┘
```

Note that the `FormVersion` has a composite primary key consisting of the Form ID and a version number.

When we persist the entities above (one entity of each kind), and then try to fetch them - e.g. fetching a StepConfiguration entity by its ID - the returned formVersion field on the FormOption entities is  **null**. This is not what we would expect because the data was saved with non-null values, so we expect to at least have a lazy-loaded proxy rather than null.

After some investigation, we found that whether the returned field is null depends on the value of the Hibernate `max_fetch_depth` parameter.

Our questions are:

- Is there something about the way our entities are modeled that is resulting in this behaviour?
- Is this behaviour to be expected when changing the `max_fetch_depth` parameter?

In case this is a bug with Hibernate (as it was not happening in 5.x), we have logged an issue on their JIRA: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-16871.

We have created a project with the entities above and failing test cases, showing both for a max fetch depth of 0 and 1 there are values that appear to be erroneously set to null: https://github.com/philiplowney/hibernate-max-fetch-depth-bug

The entities are as follows:

```java
@Entity
public class StepConfiguration {

    public StepConfiguration() { }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "configuration", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<FormOption> formOptions;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<FormOption> getFormOptions() {
        return formOptions;
    }

    public void setFormOptions(Set<FormOption> formOptions) {
        this.formOptions = formOptions;
    }
}

@Entity
public class FormOption {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stepConfiguration_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_FormOption_StepConfiguration"))
    private StepConfiguration configuration;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_FormOption_FormVersion"), value = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "form_id", updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "versionNumber", updatable = false)
    })
    private FormVersion formVersion;

    public FormOption() {
    }

    public FormOption(FormVersion formVersion) {
        this.formVersion = formVersion;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public StepConfiguration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    public void setConfiguration(StepConfiguration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public FormVersion getFormVersion() {
        return formVersion;
    }

    public void setFormVersion(FormVersion formVersion) {
        this.formVersion = formVersion;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Form {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.form")
    private List<FormVersion> versions;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<FormVersion> getVersions() {
        return versions;
    }

    public void setVersions(List<FormVersion> versions) {
        this.versions = versions;
    }
}


@Entity
public class FormVersion {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected FormVersionId id;

    public FormVersionId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(FormVersionId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public FormVersion() {
        id = new FormVersionId();
    }

    public FormVersion(Form form, int version) {
        this();
        this.id.setForm(form);
        this.id.setVersionNumber(version);
    }


}

@Embeddable
public class FormVersionId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_id")
    private Form form;

    private Integer versionNumber;

    public Form getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(Form form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public Integer getVersionNumber() {
        return versionNumber;
    }

    public void setVersionNumber(Integer versionNumber) {
        this.versionNumber = versionNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof FormVersionId)) {
            return false;
        }
        FormVersionId that = (FormVersionId) o;
        return form.getId().equals(that.form.getId()) && versionNumber.equals(that.versionNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(form, versionNumber);
    }
}
```

Our test cases look as follows, which we execute for different `max_fetch_depth` values by configuring different persistence units:

```java
public abstract class AbstractTestCase {

    private StepConfiguration stepConfiguration;

    private FormOption formOption;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    protected abstract String getEntityManagerName();

    @Before
    public void init() throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(AbstractTestCase.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("database.properties"));
        entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManagerName(), properties).createEntityManager();

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        Form form = new Form();
        entityManager.persist(form);

        FormVersion formVersion = new FormVersion(form, 1);

        entityManager.persist(formVersion);

        stepConfiguration = new StepConfiguration();

        formOption = new FormOption();
        formOption.setConfiguration(stepConfiguration);
        formOption.setFormVersion(formVersion);
        Set<FormOption> formOptions = new HashSet<>();
        formOptions.add(formOption);
        stepConfiguration.setFormOptions(formOptions);

        entityManager.persist(stepConfiguration);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.clear();
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.createQuery("DELETE from FormOption").executeUpdate();
        entityManager.createQuery("DELETE from StepConfiguration").executeUpdate();
        entityManager.createQuery("DELETE from FormVersion").executeUpdate();
        entityManager.createQuery("DELETE from Form").executeUpdate();
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void formVersionLoadTest() {
        Query fetchQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM StepConfiguration s WHERE s.id = :id");
        fetchQuery.setParameter("id", stepConfiguration.getId());
        StepConfiguration configuration = (StepConfiguration) fetchQuery.getSingleResult();

        assertNotNull(configuration.getFormOptions());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, configuration.getFormOptions().size());
        configuration.getFormOptions().forEach(formOption -> {
            FormVersion fv = formOption.getFormVersion();
            assertNotNull(fv);
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void formOptionsLoadTest() {
        Query fetchQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT fo FROM FormOption fo");
        List<FormOption> fos = (List<FormOption>) fetchQuery.getResultList();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, fos.size());
        fos.forEach(formOption -> {
            FormVersion fv = formOption.getFormVersion();
            assertNotNull(fv);
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void singleFormOptionLoadTest() {
        Query fetchQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT fo FROM FormOption fo WHERE fo.id = :id");
        fetchQuery.setParameter("id", formOption.getId());
        FormOption fo = (FormOption) fetchQuery.getSingleResult();
        FormVersion fv = fo.getFormVersion();
        assertNotNull(fv);
    }
}
```

The output of these tests is as follows: [Test case results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdkxX.png)

As per the output above, the following fails when the `max_fetch_depth`  parameter is zero:

```java
        Query fetchQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM StepConfiguration s WHERE s.id = :id");
        fetchQuery.setParameter("id", stepConfiguration.getId());
        StepConfiguration configuration = (StepConfiguration) fetchQuery.getSingleResult();

        assertNotNull(configuration.getFormOptions());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, configuration.getFormOptions().size());
        configuration.getFormOptions().forEach(formOption -> {
            FormVersion fv = formOption.getFormVersion();
            assertNotNull(fv); // <-- This assertion fails for max_fetch_depth 0
        });
```

... and the following two tests fail for `max_fetch_depth` 1:

```java
    @Test
    public void formOptionsLoadTest() {
        Query fetchQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT fo FROM FormOption fo");
        List<FormOption> fos = (List<FormOption>) fetchQuery.getResultList();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, fos.size());
        fos.forEach(formOption -> {
            FormVersion fv = formOption.getFormVersion();
            assertNotNull(fv); // <-- This assertion fails for max_fetch_depth 1
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void singleFormOptionLoadTest() {
        Query fetchQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT fo FROM FormOption fo WHERE fo.id = :id");
        fetchQuery.setParameter("id", formOption.getId());
        FormOption fo = (FormOption) fetchQuery.getSingleResult();
        FormVersion fv = fo.getFormVersion();
        assertNotNull(fv); // <-- This assertion fails for max_fetch_depth 1
    }
```

Our pom.xml's dependencies block is as follows:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using that property the way it was intended? I'm not a hibernate expert, but from forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=928842 and access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_web_server/… , I don't think you should be expecting a fully complete model being returned or that anything is made lazy. That is what JPA fetch/load graphs are for.  Your bug implies though that this used to work as you wanted, so is a regression in behavior, documented or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you @Chris. We did not expect the max_fetch_depth property to be a cause of this issue either, but it was only after changing it did we see that the behaviour changed. For this reason we based our tests around changing the value of this property to make the issue appear/disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to have been a regression issue in Hibernate and is  [tracked on Hibernate's JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16871).

As per the ticket, this was fixed in Hibernate [version 6.2.7](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HHH/versions/32170/tab/release-report-all-issues).